# Linux permissions group vs others

Tags: linux, permissions

Let's suppose that for a certain file the permissions look like this:

```
rw----r--
```

Does this mean that everyone except for the group members have read access to the file, or that `r` which appears for others overrides the group `-` and gives read access to the group members as well?

Is there any difference for directories?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that will grant read permission to everyone but the members of the group. It doesn't matter if it's a directory or not. ACLs would probably be better in a situation where one would like to do that.